# What does it mean when numbers end with U

Tags: c, literals

As in this code:

```
int nx = (int)((rev3[gx]) / 193U);
```

Whats with the U in the end of 193 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `u` is `unsigned`, that is: `1` is the `int` value 1, and `1u` is the `unsigned int` value 1.

Comment: And the effect of it in this case is that if `rev3[gx]` is an int, and therefore could be negative, that it will be converted to `unsigned` before being divided by 193. On my machine `(int)(-1 / 193)` is 0, whereas `(int)(-1 / 193U)` is 22253716. But if `rev3[gx]` is a signed integer type *bigger* than int, then the U makes no difference to the result: `(-1LL/193U) == (-1LL/193)`, both are type long long. Got to love them integer promotion rules.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the number is an `unsigned int`, which is a data type much like an `int` except that it has no negative values, which is a trade-off it makes so that it can store larger values (twice as large as a regular `int`).

Answer (score 2):

It means it's an `unsigned int` constant. It's a way of telling the compiler to use a specific type for a constant where it wouldn't otherwise know the type. A naked 193 would be treated as an `int` normally.

It's similar to the `L` suffix for `long`, the `ULL` for `unsigned long long` and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

U means unsigned.

Have a look here for more: http://cplus.about.com/od/learnc/ss/variables_6.htm

Answer (score 0):

It means to treat the value as an unsigned value